# Ubuntu update-rc.d problems

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I am trying to get a start up script to work, i have a file /etc/init.d/blah (with 755 permissions) with the contents http://pastebin.com/m4131b7c6. I have run "update-rc.d -f blah defaults". But when I reboot the script is not executing, can one of you help me out?

Comment: What is the output of `update-rc.d`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add specific information for update-rc.d to your script.
You'll find an example in /etc/init.d/skeleton

Comment: Cheers grub. That worked.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should take a look at `/etc/init.d/skeleton` in particular, but also other scripts in that folder, as a model for your script.

From `man update-rc.d`:

```
INSTALLING INIT SCRIPT LINKS
       update-rc.d has two modes of operation for installing scripts into  the
       boot  sequence.  A legacy mode where command line arguments are used to
       decide the sequence and runlevel configuration, and  the  default  mode
       where dependency and runlevel information in the init.d script LSB com‐
       ment header is used instead.  Such header is required to be present  in
       init.d  scripts.   See the insserv(8) manual page for details about the
       LSB header format.
```